# Finding the largest value in a 2D array

Tags: java, beginner, array

I'm pretty new to Java and programming in general and I'm doing practice problems from my textbook over the summer to try to get ahead. This is a simple program that finds the largest value in a 2D array. I'm just looking for feedback on the organization of my code as well as any improvements I can make so that I can build solid habits going forward.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number of rows and columns in the array: ");

    //Creates a temporary two-dimensional array whose size is the next two inputed integers
    double[][] temp = new double[input.nextInt()][input.nextInt()];

    //Populates the temp array with inputed values
    System.out.println("Enter the array: ");
    for(int i=0; i < temp.length; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j < temp[0].length; j++) {
            temp[i][j] = input.nextDouble();
        }
    }
    input.close();

    //Creates a new Location object that is equal to the object returned from the locateLargest() method call
    Location location = Location.locateLargest(temp);               

    System.out.println("The location of the largest element is " + location.maxValue + " at (" + location.row + ", " + location.column + ")");



    }
}

public class Location {
    public int row=0, column=0;
    public double maxValue = 0;

    public Location() {
    }

    /*
     * Accepts a two-dimensional array as the parameter.
     * Creates a new Location object.
     * Returns a Location object with maxValue at position (0,0) unless a larger value is found.
     */
        public static Location locateLargest(double[][] a) {
        Location location = new Location();        
        location.maxValue=a[0][0];

            for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                for(int j=0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
                    if(a[i][j] > location.maxValue) {
                        location.maxValue = a[i][j];
                        location.row = i;
                        location.column = j;
                    }
                }

            }

            return location;
       }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Obligatory disclaimer**: My opinion.

---

I can see that you are a beginner - it's a little hard to explain what you should work on, because the path you're taking toward finding the highest value in an array is a little hard to understand.

Normally, you'd just need to do something like

```
public static double findHighestValue(double[][] doubles) {
    double currentHighestValue = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int row = 0; row < doubles.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < doubles[row].length; col++) {
            double value = doubles[row][col];
            if (value > currentHighestValue) {
                currentHighestValue = value;
            }
        }
    }
    return currentHighestValue; 
}
```

to find the maximum value of a 2D array (which is the question), but instead, you're returning an object `Location`.

I can understand where you got the class name idea -- locating a value -- however, it's counter-intuitive. Instead, a class name such as `Case` or `Square` would be a bit more descriptive due to the fact that the noun location has multiple meanings.

I'll show you what I would do to answer the question (finds the largest value in a 2D array), and then, to help you learn, I'll give you some tips on the code you already wrote.

As this question is extremely wide, I won't go as far as to explain everything, but I'll give you a few pointers.

### What I would do

This isn't a really complex problem per se, so there's not a lot to explain.

Since you want to know the coordinates of the maximum value (column and row), we still need to create a custom class.

First, you must determine what the class represents. 
In this case, it represents an element in a multidimensional array, so like I said earlier, I'll just use something a little bit more intuitive like a `Case`.

#### Why is `Case` a better name?

If you visualize the 2D array, it looks like this:

```
 _ _ _
|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|
```

And each square looks like a case.

Each case contains a value, and a position determined by the row number and the column number of the case, so those 3 parameters will be our fields:

```
public class Case {

    private int row;
    private int col;
    private double value;

    public Case(int row, int col, double value) {
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getRow() {
        return row;
    }

    public void setRow(int row) {
        this.row = row;
    }

    public int getCol() {
        return col;
    }

    public void setCol(int col) {
        this.col = col;
    }

    public double getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

With this new class in mind, the method we would use to find the case with the highest value would be something like this:

```
public static Case findHighestValue(double[][] doubles) {
    Case highestCase = new Case(-1, -1, Double.MIN_VALUE);
    for (int row = 0; row < doubles.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < doubles[row].length; col++) {
            double value = doubles[row][col];
            if (value > highestCase.getValue()) {
                highestCase = new Case(row, col, value);
            }
        }
    }
    return highestCase;
}
```

I would put that in an interface named something like `CaseUtils` (unless you have another class related to cases, e.g. `CaseService`, but since you initially only had a `Main` class and a `Location` class, I assume there isn't any), which would look like this:

```
public interface CaseUtils {

    static Case findHighestValue(double[][] doubles) {
        Case highestCase = new Case(-1, -1, Double.MIN_VALUE);
        for (int row = 0; row < doubles.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < doubles[row].length; col++) {
                double value = doubles[row][col];
                if (value > highestCase.getValue()) {
                    highestCase = new Case(row, col, value);
                }
            }
        }
        return highestCase;
    }

}
```

That way, if you want to add more methods of the same type (e.g. `findLowestValue`), you'll be able to add them there too.

As for how to implement it in your main, you just need to do something like this:

```
Case c = CaseUtils.findHighestValue(array);
System.out.println("The position of the case with the highest value is " + c.getValue()
        + " at (" + c.getRow() + ", " + c.getCol() + ")");
```

## Tips on your current code

Your comments on the method `locateLargest` do not conform with the javadoc convention:

```
/*
 * Accepts a two-dimensional array as the parameter.
 * Creates a new Location object.
 * Returns a Location object with maxValue at position (0,0) unless a larger value is found.
 */
```

should instead be something like:

```
/**
 * Locates the largest double
 * @param a two-dimensional array as the parameter.
 * @return Location object with maxValue at position (0,0) unless a larger value is found.
 */
```

If you want to read more about Javadoc, I suggest you read [this article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html).

The class `Location` should not have public fields, but private fields with public getters and setters instead. As for why, you can search online, but this is also a good explanation: [Why do we need private variables?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/143736/why-do-we-need-private-variables)

If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

## NOTE

I used the name `Case` to highlight that the class name should clearly explain what it is. However, I wouldn't personally use that class name and instead, I would use `Cell` because the keyword `case` is reserved (switch case).

Comment: personally I would not use `Square` as it is related to the display and graphics terminology.  perhaps `Cell` is more appropriate (think of the 2d array as a spreadsheet containing cells)

Comment: You're right, I had totally forgotten about the existence of that word